# can I create kubernetes networks in a host project, then share them to service project using deployment manager?

Tags: google-deployment-manager

I have a host project and service project.  My networks are created in host project, and compute/kubernetes resources in service project are created in these shared network.

when doing this manually, I would create the subnets in host project, associate the network to the service project, share the subnets to those 3 service accounts in service project and assign network user role to them.  how much of this can I do in deployment manager?

using deployment manager, I can create subnets, but I can't get the subnets to share.  here is my code

```
resources:
  - name: mytest-kube
    type: subnetwork.py
    properties:
      network: "/projects/xxxxxx/global/networks/xxxxx-vpc1"
      region: us-east1
      ipCidrRange: x.x.x.0/24
      privateIpGoogleAccess: true
      enableFlowLogs: true
      secondaryIpRanges:
      - rangeName: mytest-kube-pod
        ipCidrRange: x.x.x.0/24
      - rangeName: mytest-kube-service
        ipCidrRange: x.x.x.0/24
    accessControl:
      gcpIamPolicy:
        bindings:
          - members:
            - serviceAccount:xxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
            - serviceAccount:xxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
            - serviceAccount:service-xxxxxxx@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
            role: roles/compute.networkUser
```

Comment: Can you include the details of `subnetwork.py`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [document](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/shared-vpc-with-deployment-manager), which mentioned the step by step instuctions on how to create shared vpc. Please keep in mind, Shared VPC is an Organization-level feature. As such, it requires some Organization-level policies to be configured—the service account used by Deployment Manager needs specific roles at the Organization level.

Comment: I am not trying to use deployment manager to create a shared VPC.

I am trying to use deployment manager to create kubernettes subnets in an existing shared VPC, hence the question about subnet sharing.

Comment: Are you trying to make a secondary range in an existing subnet or you are trying to create new subnets with secondary ranges in an existing VPC?  
In either case, using deployment manager to share a subnet does not work well (it's not a simple API call)

Comment: I was trying to create the network for Kubernetes cluster, so yes, the primary range and secondary range.  but thanks for the information that this cannot be done.